# Linq to SQL anonymous types return null

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a query that returns multiple result sets. But if one of the results is null, then nothing is returned. Is it possible to recover the data even if this result set is null?

Example:

```
from u in Units
select new
{
    Unit = u,
    AgreementType = from at in AgreementTypes
                    select new { at },
    OptionRightsType = from ortp in OptionRightsTypes
                       select new { ortp }
}
```

In this example, if Unit is null, then no records are returned. Is it possible to recover the other result sets even if unit is null?

**UPDATE**

Example:

```
from u in Units
where u.Id == 1000
select new
{
    Unit = u,
    AgreementType = from at in AgreementTypes
                    select new { at },
    OptionRightsType = from ortp in OptionRightsTypes
                       select new { ortp }
}
```

In the above example, I would exist the result to recover three IQueryable types, Unit, AgreementType, OptionRightsType.

This is the case, but if the query does not find a unit with id equal to 1000, then it returns null.

Can I still recover the AgreementType and OptionRightsType types when the unit return no records?

**UPDATE 2**

What I am trying to do is:

```
from u in Units
where u.Id == 1000
select new
{
    Unit = u
}
```

and

```
from at in AgreementTypes
           select new 
           { 
               at,
               OptionRightsType = from ortp in OptionRightsTypes
                                  select new { ortp }
            }
```

Two completely separate queries.

I just thought that I could join them together as the second query just pulls static data back

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Your query is broken. It makes no sense to `select new { at }` or `select new { ortp }`. You could just do `select at` and `select ortp` respectively. But then you could just do `AgreementType = AgreementTypes` & `OptionRightsType = OptionRightsTypes`. But that's weird. I'm thinking that you somehow want `AgreementType` and `OptionRightsType` to be a join based on `u`. Is that right?

Comment: It's not clear at all what you want to achieve. Your query just returns *all* `AgreementTypes` and `OptionRightsTypes` for each instance of `Unit`. This does not make sense. Can you please be more clear on what do you expect to obtain with your query?

Comment: Enigmativity, I am just trying to reduce the number of calls to the database. So in my ignorance, I though, ah add the extra required lookups to the query. So AgreementType and OptionRightsType are just that. They are to be used as lookup for some dropdowns.

Comment: See msdn left outer join : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: I am not using a join, because the data is not linked. This is just to pull the data back thus reducing the round trips.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want. Are you sure they data structure will be as you want as well? For each Unit you will have all the AgreementTypes & OptionRightTypes, this could be a lot of duplication of the same data if more than one Unit is found. Your Update 2 to us more clearer to me what the code should be doing.

Comment: @gilesrpa - Please use the `@` notifications when replying to someone.

Comment: @Enigmativity sorry, did not know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would say not to do what you are trying to do and go with Enigmativity's answer

To someone maintaining this code is is not clear what the intention is.
Also it may not result in the data structure you intended. For each Unit found it will select all of the AgreementType and OptionRightsType data. This could be a lot of duplication of the same data.

```
from u in Units
select new
{
    Unit = u,
    AgreementType = from at in AgreementTypes
                    select new { at },
    OptionRightsType = from ortp in OptionRightsTypes
                       select new { ortp }
}
```

Splitting the code into two separate queries as per your Update 2 makes it clearer what you are trying to achieve.

You are getting the Units you want.

```
from u in Units
where u.Id == 1000
select new
{
    Unit = u
}
```

You are getting all the AgreementTypes and OptionRightsTypes but not duplicating the data for each unit found.

```
from at in AgreementTypes
           select new 
           { 
               at,
               OptionRightsType = from ortp in OptionRightsTypes
                                  select new { ortp }
            }
```

May be you can ask another question as to why you wanted to do this in the first place. It sounds like you are trying to optimise your database calls. This could possible achieved another way. e.g. caching the static data.

If you still want to try and reduce these to one query then I will advise you try and write the code in SQL first and then look to see if that code can be converted into Linq.

Answer (score 1):

What it sounds like you need is this:

```
var unit = Units.Where(u => u.Id == 1000).FirstOrDefault();
var agreementTypes = AgreementTypes.ToArray();
var optionRightsTypes = OptionRightsTypes.ToArray();
```

Don't worry about network calls until you know you have an actual problem with the speed of the calls.

Answer (score 0):

if you have some relationship then you can use left outer join:

```
var result = from u in units
                         join at in AgreementTypes on u equals at into A
                         from at in A.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join ortp in OptionRightsTypes on u equals ortp into B
                         from ortp in B.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where u.Id == 1000
                         select new
                         {
                             Unit = u ? u.SomeValue: "No units",
                             att = att ? att.SomeValue: "No att",
                             ortp = ortp.SomeValue ?? "No ortp"
                         };
```

Comment: There is no relationship, I was looking to reduce traffic by collecting the required data, including data used for dropdown lists on the view with one linq to sql call

Answer (score 0):

From the answer given and further testing of my own code, I can pull the lookup data out the database in a single query as per my updated example. I am now using this to pull complete models from my database where it is then converted into a DTO using a static class.

I tried AutoMapper, but needed the extra granularity obtained by using a static class to convert between objects.